# Transmission of signal power in the RF for relays

Tags: power, digital-logic, rf, relay

I'm trying to solve one problem for transmitting a signal to the outputs of the chips.

I need to transmit digital signals with an amplitude of 20 V and a maximum current of 500 mA, at a frequency up to 1 GHz, thus the relay must provide a transmitted signal power of 10 Watts at 1 GHz frequency.

When searching for relays of this type, I came across the problem that, with such signal parameters, found relays are able to switch only about 1-3 Watts (**Maximum carry power**) [https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3626846.pdf],[https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g6k_2f_rf.pdf]. There is information available about switching power reaching up to 10 watts during switching (**Contact input power**,**Maximum switching power**), but this is already the maximum limitation for me, and this does not take into account the transient current during switching.

A little bit about the structure of the project: in my thesis, it is necessary to develop a multiplexer that switches signals from the "voltage source module", "pulse generator module" and "meter module" into a block where CMOS type chips are connected. The technical specification for the project states that "The maximum pulse frequency of the signal sources is 20 MHz." At the same time, for the "pulse generator" there is a mention that "the rise and fall time of the front should not exceed 1 ns / V," which, as the senior engineer told me, requires signal processing at a frequency of 1 GHz

Please tell me where I have made a mistake. Do I need to look for a relay with a large supply of switching power without paying attention to the signal parameters, as they will most likely be satisfactory [[https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1972527.pdf]](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1972527.pdf)? Or are the relays capable of transmitting the described signal?

Comment: Since your requirement as well as these relays are very specialized, how about simply transmitting the data across two contacts (2 pole relay)? Or is that considered too risky for the application?

Comment: Maybe that's enough. I don't understand very well how the power of a digital signal is transmitted. So far, it is known for sure that the maximum current consumed by the chip is 0.5 A, the signal processing frequency is 1 GHz, and the voltage range was | 20 V|. The purpose is to switch test signals to a chip

Comment: A digital signal with an amplitude of 20 V sounds unlikely, and you're in RF, so defining the current makes little sense in this context: You're conducting an electromagnetic wave, not an AC current. Could you tell us more about what this signal is?

Comment: The 1972527 relays are just as good, if not better, than your other options at RF performance (insertion loss and VSWR), so unless there's a severe financial penalty, go with them. Note that switching RF can be a problem if your feedlines are not matched to some tame impedance like 50 ohms. A high VSWR in the load can throw many times the expected voltage across or current through the contacts as they open, causing them to erode orders of magnitude faster than switching the same power in a matched system.

Comment: A diagram or schematic showing how this will be used might help make your question more clear. For example, why are you "transmitting a signal **to** the output of some chips"? Normally a chip's output produces a signal and we need to transmit it **from** the chip to somewhere else. Why do you expect a relay to "provide" power? Relays are passive devices that just connect one terminal to the other. They don't provide power. Do you require an electromechanical switch or would a semiconductor switch be acceptable? Do you need to terminate the signal when the switch is open?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I should talk about the structure of the stand and clarify a little the description of the signals: in my thesis, it is necessary to develop a multiplexer that switches signals from a "voltage source module", a "pulse generator module", and a "meter module" into a block for CMOS chips. In general, the technical specifications state that "The maximum pulse frequency of signal sources is 20 MHz". For the pulse generator, there is mention that "the rise and fall time of the front should not exceed 1 ns / V", which requires processing the signal at a frequency of 1 GHz.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear what problem you're trying to solve. The question should be clear without having to read the comments.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you. I really need to change the question.